# How are builtin commands implemented in shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, system-calls

When a shell (e.g. `bash`) invokes an executable file, it first `fork` itself, and then its copy `execve` the executable file.

When a shell invokes builtin commands, there is no new process created, and `execve` can only operate on executable files while builtin commands are not stored in executable files.

So how are builtin commands stored, and how are they invoked in terms of system calls?

Comment: This question shows you're *expecting* a builtin command to be kind of "launched" like an external executable. Why that? they are built-ins.

Comment: There are downvotes on all questions/answers. Why's that?

Comment: Builtins are stored in an executable, it's called bash.

Comment: to add to @pfnuesel: not only are there downvotes on three agreeing answers, but also no comment at all explaining why things were downvoted; that's kind of irritating, considering the downvoter (assuming it was a single voter) was in the minority with his/her opinion

Comment: This is a case of serial downvoting and that too without leaving any comment.

Comment: @anubhava hm, shouldn't serial downvotes be caught relatively quickly?

Comment: @anubhava i.e. by the system and reverted automagically?

Answer (score 1):

"builtin command" means that you don't have to run an external program. So, no, there's no `execve` involved at all, and no, there's not even any system call necessarily involved. Your shell really just parses a command string and sees "hey, that's a builtin command, let's execute this and that function".

Answer (score 1):

You can imagine they are the same as shell functions.

So instead of launching external process the shell invokes some internal function library function which reads the input outputs the result and does pretty much the same as main function of regular program.

Answer (score 0):

The shell process itself just handles the builtin and potentially modifies itself or its environment as a result. There might not be any system calls made at all.

Comment: hm, where's the downvote coming from? this answer is as correct as any other given here.